# How prove that $w_u$ depends on $u$ continuously

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Let $u,w_u\in C[0,1]$ where $u'(0)=B\cdot u(0),u(1)=0$; $w_u'(0)=B\cdot w_u(0),w_u(1)=0$ with $B\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Here the notation $w_u$ it means dependency. Furthermore, we have the relationship:
>
> $$w_u(t)=\int_{t}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{s}f(u(x))dx-A\cdot w_u(0)\right)ds,\quad A\in\mathbb{R}^{+},f:\mathbb{R}_0^{+}\to\mathbb{R}_0^{+}\,\textrm{continuous}$$
>
> I need prove that $w_u$ depends on $u$ continuously.

---

My attempt:

I have tried with the *implicit theorem on Banach spaces* (view K.Deimling,p.148).

I defined the application:

> $$F(u,wu)=\int_t^1\left(\int_0^sf(u(x))dx−A⋅wu(0)\right)ds−wu(t)$$

I proved the continuity of $F$. Now my problem is with the *Jacobian computation* .

May I ask for help in further solving?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have tried with the implicit theorem on Banach spaces (view K.Deimling,p.148). I defined the application $$F(u,w_u)=\int_{t}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{s}f(u(x))dx-A\cdot w_u(0)\right)ds-w_u(t)$$. I proved the continuity of F, now my problem is with the Jacobian computation

Comment: Great! Include that into your post!

Comment: Could you please, show some signs of life? 